# how do i run a nodejs app on my apache server?

Tags: node.js

I will be straight to the point, I have 0 understanding of nodeJS.

I built an application in codeigniter, and I then purchased a codeigniter chat script. The chat script works, however it uses nodeJS and sockets to get real time updates.

I enabled Node in easy apache 4, but have no clue what to do next. It says i need to run node server.js

so i typed that in SSH but it says command not found.

I really don't understand anything! Any help is appreciated

Comment: Make sure you have [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/) downloaded.. Then just run your script. `Node server.js`

Comment: I tried running that command and then nothing happens in SSH

Comment: That means it worked. :) It would only log things if the `server.js` had logging.

Comment: Suggest looking into using something like runit to manage the starting and stopping of the server http://smarden.org/runit/